# How to fetch GET request variables with Vue (Router) before loading / displaying the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

When loading the login page - I want to check if there were GET variables set, and fetch them in my Vue app (So then I can change the mode displayed).

My URL and variables look like this:

> https://localhost:3000/login?user=potato&token=666

my code looks like this:

```
let routes = [
    {
        path:       '/login',
        component:  Login
    },
    {
        path:       '/login/:user/:token',
        component:  Login,
        // props:   true
        props:      ['user', 'token']
    },
    ...
];
```

...
...
...

```
export default {
    props: [ 'user', 'token' ], 
    data() {
        return {
            // Change to yours for testing, empty these before production release
            user: '',
            pass: '',
            getData: null
        };
    },
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        getPost(to.params.id, (err, post) => {
            next(vm => vm.setGetData(err, post))
        })
    },
    // When route changes and this component is already rendered,
    // the logic will be slightly different.
    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
        this.getData = null
        getPost(to.params.id, (err, post) => {
            this.setGetData(err, post)
            next()
        })
    },
    methods: {
        setGetData (err, post) {
            if (err) {
                this.error = err.toString()
            } else {
                this.getData = post
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My last try was trying to follow Vues documentation on fetching data: 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation

But it's not fully explained (`getPost is not defined`). I'm a bit new to Vue / VueRouter (I work with vanilla js or php), my question might seem basic but seriously, haven't found anything that represent a full well explained example of fetching get data.

I was told at the beggining that it's a "props" passing thing, and didn't get this right too, followed Vues doc: 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

- How do I  fetch the GET variables, **before** anything gets displayed so I have time to change the mode variable?
- Does my URL look right? `https://localhost:3000/login?user=potato&token=666` or should it look like this? `https://localhost:3000/login/potato/666`?

When handling this manually with `window.location.href` as suggested breaks my code:

```
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        console.log(window.location.href);
        if (this.getGetVariables(window.location.href)){
            console.log('has token: ' + this.token ); 
        }
        next()
    }, 

  methods: {
        // URL Variables: 
        getGetVariables: function(urlString) {
            var url = new URL(urlString);
            this.token = url.searchParams.get('token');
            console.log(this.token);
            if (!this.token) return false;
            this.user = url.searchParams.get('user');
            console.log(this.user);
        }
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGetVariables' of undefined

Seems like it's not setting variables until it reaches `create()` (I think). So where am I suppose to save the URL variables?

I tried changing the `beforeRouteEnter` name to `beforeRouteUpdate` and it's not fetching the URL properly anymore in that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the get query parameters with `this.$router.query`.

---

$route.query

type: Object

An object that contains key/value pairs of the query string. For example, for a path `/foo?user=1`, we get `$route.query.user == 1`. If there is no query the value will be an empty object.

source: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties

---

edit:

The user and token inside the path don't use the `$router.query` they are props that get filled by router and will automaticly change when the url changes.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Here an example I found using `?name=value`: https://jsfiddle.net/posva/chyLjpv0/

Here an example I found using `/:name`: https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ykf0uv0d/

Comment: YEY! That's what i was looking for. `created() {console.log($route.query.token);}` 
outputs `[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: $route is not defined"`
I tried running in my browsers console: `app.$route` just to see what's inside and i see nothing mentioning to the token or user variables. Can you please add an example that works?

Comment: You should use `created() {console.log(this.$route.query.token);}` but this is only usefull when using the `website.com/?name=value`. if you want to use the /:id/:token you should use BeforeUpdate I think. will check when I have the time.

Comment: Yes! that'a right, I get that now! having `login/something1/something2` works. but ruined my css for some weird reason.

Comment: Why is my login page without css on this url?

Comment: the css of your component shouldn't change, are you using classes?
can you show some of your html / css.

Comment: I figured out why this is happenning, i think, still in the guessing stage... This happens only when i pass variables to the url. 
The page loads a broken css file: `https://localhost:3000/login/public/css/main.css` instead of `https://localhost:3000/public/css/main.css` for some strange reason. Which code part should I add ?

Comment: awesome and glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with beforeRouteEnter is correct. You can access the get vars using vanilla JS using **window.location.href**.

I don’t know of any vue like method of getting the GET params.

Comment: So I might need to just create a method named `getPost()` that basically returns the GET variables? 
I'm not sure what it should accept from the example vue have on their website and stating `// replace "getPost" with your data fetching util / API wrapper` as a code comment

Comment: You could, or you can just the params, synchronously, and then call next. The example from the docs are related to async operations, like an api call, but this is not your use case.

Comment: Trying following that. Edited my main post. If you can please review

Comment: As per documentation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards you cannot access this inside the route. You could define your method outside the component definition. The only problem is with saving the token as you don’t have a this. You could use vuex or just store it in a module variable.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure what your last comment mean :o could you please explain more briefly

Comment: Thank you for your help, @tjeerddies solution was better for me :)